# PHP Compare date to current date does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, date

This is a wordpress site but the dates are custom and they are not post dates. I'm trying to compare an expire date to current date. It works on some dates but when expire date is on 01/01/2017 or 01/01/2016 it returns an Invalid status. Even when date is on the year 2017 it still returns invalid status. Somehow it is not consistent and I am not sure where to check and what statement might be missing.  This is the sample code. Expired date is already stored in $dates[1] and the value has a format of MM/DD/YY. I used the wordpress current_time code to call the current date. Please help. Thanks!

```
<?php 
$current_datetime = current_time( 'mysql' );
if ($dates[1] < date('m/d/Y', strtotime($current_datetime)) ){
    echo '<td class="-status"><span>Invalid</span></td>'."\n";
}
else
if ($dates[1]  >= date('m/d/Y', strtotime($current_datetime)) ){
    echo '<td class="-status"><span>Valid</span></td>'."\n";
    }   

?>
```

Comment: echo out `$current_datetime` and give me feed back

Comment: Because you are using format `m/d/Y`, you are comparing strings. So for today, `07/01/2015`, you are basically checking `if('01/01/2017'<'07/01/2015') {...} else if ('01/01/2017'>='07/01/2015') {...}`.  And since `01 < 07` is true, your `if` returns `Invalid`. You should compare using `Y-m-d` (which is returned by your [`$current_datetime = current_time( 'mysql' );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time)) as `else if ('2017-01-01'>='2015-07-01')` would return true, resulting in `Valid`.

Comment: use `strtotime` to compare date format.. and make sure you're date format is Y-m-d because i know m/d/Y is always gets some weird strtotime thats same like d/m/Y... example `strtotime($date[1]) < strtotime($current_datetime)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was the format of the date, specifically the year of the date had the problem. Though changing the format would be another way. I just altered by using explode on php which basically separates the date format if you are using '/' and assign to an array. Then compare the current year to year of the expire date.

```
<?php 
$expire_year = explode('/', $dates[1]);
if ($dates[1] < date('m/d/Y', strtotime($current_date_test))){
    if($expire_year[2] > date('Y', strtotime($current_date_test))){ 
    echo '<td class="-status"><span>Valid</span></td>'."\n";
    }

else{ 
    echo '<td class="-status"><span>Invalid</span></td>'."\n";
    }

else{
    if ($dates[1]  >= date('m/d/Y', strtotime($current_date_test)) ){ 
        echo '<td class="-status"><span>Valid</span></td>'."\n";
    }   
}                                   
?>
```

Thanks for the idea!